# Import shapefile in GEE Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I know how to use GEE with JavaScript to import the shapefile, which is just uploading file to asset, then import it in JavaScript code, just like this:

```
var counties: Table user/wxystudio/cb_2016_us_county
```

It will be automatically transferred to a FeatureCollection object in GEE.

But how can I import this file as FeatureCollection in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the Earth Engine Python API using `pip install earthengine-api`

Once you install ee module, open your Jupyter Notebook and run these followinge codes to import the feature collection

```
import ee

# Trigger the authentication flow.
ee.Authenticate()

# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize()

feature_collection = ee.FeatureCollection('user/wxystudio/cb_2016_us_county')
```

If you don't want to install earth engine python api on your local machine, you can always try coding on [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). The ee module is installed by default there.